# What is the possible view controller design behind Safari's bookmark manager?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

Since [iOS human interface guideline](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/) does not recommend put tab bar on the top, I am wondering what's the possible implementation for a Safari bookmark manager like below.

How to switch views instantly when I tap a button on the tab bar? The manager itself should be a `container view`, but how to add three views and change instantly? It would be helpful if there is any sample code.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing at the top is not a tab bar. It is a segmented control. So this could be a tab bar controller with no tab bar, driven from the segmented control. But it has a nav bar and a toolbar so it is more likely just a single navigation controller with swapping tables and other interface.

Comment: An easy way to do this would be to put all three table views into a sideways scroll view that the user can't scroll, and just scroll in code without animation to bring in a different table view. But it looks to me like they are not doing that, because I see a slight fade-out-fade-in (dissolve), I think, when you switch segments.